# When Swift variable changes it doesn't update in Objective C class

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift4

I'm new to Swift and I know that the problem I'm having here is down to a complete lack of understanding of how transferring data between classes works.

I have a Swift class with an isRecording bool originally set to false. When I press the recording button on my app isRecording is set to true.

I want to use isRecording in an objective c class. I have access to the variable and am able to print it out. The problem is when isRecording gets set to true in the swift class it is still false in the objective c class. How can I get isRecording to update as the button is pressed.

Swift Class:

```
class SessionHandler : NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

 @objc public var isRecording = false
```

Objective C class

```
#import "DlibTester-Swift.h"
SessionHandler *session = [[SessionHandler alloc]init];



//....
    cout << "isRecording is " << session.isRecording << endl;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the same instance in both cases?

Comment: In the Objective C class I am using session.isRecording to access the isRecording var from the swift class. Is this correct? Do I need to do more?

Comment: Most importantly, you need to avoid using `SessionHandler()` in Swift *and* `[[SessionHandler alloc] init]` in ObjC, because that would create two independent instances. Choose one side to create your handler, eg. in a Singleton, and make sure the other side accesses that same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to allocate a new instance of SessionHandler instead of requesting the already allocated SessionHandler instance allocated in Swift.

Find where you declared and instantiated SessionHandler in Swift, and make sure you have an @objc accessible function or variable to access it from Objective-C.  Whatever you do, do not create a new instance of SessionHander from Objective-C otherwise for sure they will not be the same values.

---

Edit: Singleton...

In case you can guarantee you only ever have one SessionHandler in your entire project, you may want to look into how to define and use a Singleton.  So that you can do [SessionHandler sharedHandler].isRecording from Objective-C, and use it as SessionHandler.sharedHandler in Swift.  Ref: https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand now why it's not working but I'm still unsure of how to fix it. The SessionHandler is being instantiated in FaceDetectionViewController.swift. I don't really understand how I can access it from Objective-C. In FaceDetectionViewController I've created a function to return sessionHandler.isRecording. Then in Objective-C I've done FaceDetectionViewController *controller = [[FaceDetectionViewController alloc]init] BOOL isRecording = [controller getIsRecording]; This isn't working. How do I pass sessionHandler.isRecording to Objective-C?

Comment: See my updated answer, I added a reference to Singleton pattern which may be of help to you

Comment: Thank you, using a Singleton is what I needed and it's now working. Thanks for your help!